# Should we use comma after -ing phrases?

Tags: commas

Might seem a trivial question to many of you, but the question occurred to me a lot of times: Do we need comma after -ing forms like the followings?

> Walking down the street **,** Jim hears a sound.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a comma for the following reason:

If you were to take out the non-essential information, *down the street*, the sentence would read strangely without the comma: "Walking Jim hears a sound." Without the pause between *walking* and *Jim*, it reads as though the sentence is about a person who has been given the nickname Walking Jim, rather than being about a person named Jim who is walking, if that makes sense.

Therefore, a comma is required after the -ing form of a verb before the noun to which it refers.